# Veeam Hyper-V DNS and Credentials

Tags: hyper-v, veeam

Keep in mind that i just started with Veeam (backup and replication) and Hyper-V, English also isn't my first language, so please excuse any mistakes.

What i want to do is, Back-up a (standalone) Virtual machine with Windows server 2012 R2.

I installed Veeam and Hyper-V on a windows server 2012 R2, 
on Hyper-V i got a virtual machine with windows server 2012 R2.

My problem is that the DNS or IP is not correct, so i want to know what i need to fill in as DNS. Is it like: "VRm Name"."Domain".local?

And the domain is it the domain of my network, or domain of my virtual server?

Also i want to know what i need to fill in at the credentials,
do i need to fill in the computer name and username of my computer running hyper-v and veeam, like this: "Computername"\"Username"?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to add your Hyper-V server into Veeam: https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/hyperv/add_hyperv_server.html?ver=95

Note: You may use Hostname\Username or Domain\Username to specify credentials that will be used in Veeam to communicate with Hyper-V. You should use your domain admin.

2. Then create your 1st backup job: https://helpcenter.veeam.com/docs/backup/hyperv/backup_job.html?ver=95
3. If you are on this step - you are great!
            ...but I will suggest you to RTFM some day.